# How do you reason whether an exercise has a dynamic programming solution or not? If it has then how do you develop the algorithm to solve it?

Tags: logic, dynamic-programming

What conditions does a programming problem need to meet in order to be solved trough dynamic programming? What reasoning do you do in order to find out?

Once you conclude that it indeed has a DP solution then how would you go on about creating a DP algorithm that solves it? What's the logic behind creating such algorithms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem must meet two conditions in order to be solved trough dynamic programming. Citing [Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844), chapter 15:

> **Optimal substructure** if an optimal solution to the problem contains within it optimal solutions to subproblems.
>
> When a recursive algorithm revisits the same problem repeatedly, we say that the optimization problem has **overlapping subproblems**.

In [The Algorithm Design Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849967202), chapter 8, the author describes the three steps involved in solving a problem by dynamic programming:

> 1. Formulate the answer as a recurrence relation or recursive algorithm.
> 2. Show that the number of different parameter values taken on by your recur- rence is bounded by a (hopefully small) polynomial.
> 3. Specify an order of evaluation for the recurrence so the partial results you need are always available when you need them.

As usual, the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) contains an extensive discussion on the topic, if you want to dig deeper.